# Python - make_archive zip in multiprocess pool not working properly

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, zip, pool

I want to create a zip archive from multiple processes at the same time.
When I've used pool from multiprocessing.
Some of zip archive have not been created.
It seems that the close method do not wait for processes to end
Below the process launcher:

```
import os
import sys
import json
from multiprocessing import Pool
from shutil import copyfile, make_archive
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

def launch_traitment(path, path_upload):
    print(path)
    with Pool(processes=NB_PROCESS) as pool:
        for dir in os.listdir(path):
            pool.apply_async(compute_dir,(dir,path,path_upload,))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
...
def compute_dir(dir, path, path_upload):

    working_path = path+'/'+dir
    deleteAck(working_path+'/'+dir+'.ack')
    execute(dir, path)
    generateZIP(dir, working_path, path_upload)
...
def generateZIP(dir, working_path, path_upload):
    lst_file_meta_data = dir.split('_')
    if len(lst_file_meta_data) < 3:
        print(f"File {dir} incorrect naming")
        return 1

    provider = lst_file_meta_data[0]
    registration = lst_file_meta_data[1]
    session_date = lst_file_meta_data[2]

    zip_file = path_upload+'/'+provider+'/'+registration

    if not os.path.exists(zip_file+'/'+ dir +'.zip'):
        print('Génération du ZIP : ', zip_file+'/'+ dir +'.zip')
        if not os.path.exists(zip_file):
            os.makedirs(zip_file)
        make_archive(zip_file+'/'+ dir, 'zip', working_path)
```

I've tried to create zip with the system command but I had the same problem:

```
os.system(f'zip -r -j {zip_file}/{dir}.zip {working_path}')
```

I've also tried to put a try except but no exception has been thrown

Comment: Maybe you need the pool.join() to come before the pool.close()?
Try to print 'begin' at the beginning of each zip job and 'end' at the end. Then compare the count of 'begin' and 'end'.

Comment: I 've already tried to do the join before but it throws an error. The documentation says that you should close or terminate before calling join.

Comment: Where is the code for `make_archive`?

Comment: I have edited my previous post, it's an import.

Comment: Try adding `pool.wait()` before the `pool.close()`. Your code also needs `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool` or similar.

Comment: I've added every imports in my post. I've also tried to add the wait method on my apply_async result but it makes my function to work synchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. I've a number of processes lower than the number of processes launched by my for loop. So if the process have not finished his treatment, it's overrided by a new one.